# webpack hot middleware split chunk

Tags: webpack, code-splitting, webpack-hot-middleware

I am trying utilise webpack code splitting. Everything looks like its working well, webpack splits the code correct, dependencies, pretty much as expected.

Except i can't get it to work with hot-module-replacement.

I successfully load 127.0.0.1:8009/main.js

But main.js is trying to load
127.0.0.1:8001/assets/1.chunk.js

Does it make sense? I must be missing something.

*I'm running my node server at 127.0.0.1:8001 and the hot-middleware client at 127.0.0.1:8009*

** main.js**

```
require.ensure([], function (require) {
  var admin = require('./admin');
}, 'admin');
```

**My Webpack config**

```
const PATHS = {
  root: __dirname,
  client: path.join(__dirname, '../', 'browser', 'scripts'),
  public: path.join(__dirname, '../', '../', 'public')
};

var webpackConfig = {
    hotPort: process.env.PORT_HOT,
    devtool: 'eval',
    name: 'browser',
    resolve: {
      root: PATHS.root,
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.styl'],
      modulesDirectories: [
        'node_modules',
        PATHS.client,
      ],
    },
    entry: {
      main: ['main', hotMiddlewareScript]
    },
    output: {
      path: PATHS.public,
      filename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: '/assets/'
    },
    module: {
        noParse: [
            /lodash/
        ],
        loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['babel']
        }
    },
};
```

**Simple Hot Server**

```
const app = express();

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackDev(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(webpackHot(compiler));

app.listen(webpackConfig.hotPort);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the publicPath to hot-middleware client did it

```
output: {
  path: PATHS.public,
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js',
  publicPath: http://127.0.0.1:8009
}
```